# JDBC Teradata Sink: How to insert null values

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, teradata, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to insert data from Kafka to Teradata. The payload has some null values, and the JDBC sink is throwing the following error.

```
[Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.10] [Error 1063] [SQLState HY000] null is not supported as a data value with this variant of the setObject method; use the setNull method or the setObject method with a targetSqlType parameter
```

My connector config:

```
name=teradata-sink-K_C_OSUSR_DGL_DFORM_I1-V2
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=connectionString
topics=POPS-P-OSUSR_DGL_DFORM_I1-J-V2-CAL-OUT
topic.prefix=
table.name.format=K_C_OSUSR_DGL_DFORM_I1_V2
batch.size=50000
errors.tolerance=all
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name=POPS-P-OSUSR_DGL_DFORM_I1-V2-CAL-DEAD
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor=1
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I do not know if I have to change some code into the sink or just change the connector config.

Comment: What Kafka Version are you using?

Comment: Also, can you share the configuration of the connector?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous done, I thinks the version is 3.2.2

Comment: What does your target schema look like? And what does your source message look like?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error from some line that surely look like this:

`ps.setObject(1, val);`

This one will throw an exception if the `val` you try to insert has a `null` value.

The error is telling that you must specify the data type of the null values incoming. You could do this:

```
ps.setObject(1, val, Types.VARCHAR);
```

This way you are casting `NULL` to a `VARCHAR`, one of the supported `targetSqlTypes`.

Another option for the same purpose:

```
ps.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR) ;
```

Comment: So I need to change that line inside the JDBC Kafka Sink?

Comment: I really don't know the details of that sink as never used, but I guess you should. There's some more info here, as well as another way of achieveing this: 
 https://community.teradata.com/t5/Third-Party-Software/Passing-NULL-values-to-a-TERADATA-sp-using-Teradata-NET-provider/td-p/3925

Comment: The Sink connector uses JDBC. The answer here depends on if the source message matches the target schema. If it does, then there should be a new dialect (https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/tree/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect) for the connector for Teradata specifically to handle whatever the data translation issue is. If the schemas don't match, then aligning them should work and not need any actual code changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem we have is we are using the standard Kafka Connect to create a sink (we are not coding any custom connector).

We have configured both .properties files for worker and connector to create a link between the topic and the teradata table, and we run it using

```
.../confluent/bin/connect-standalone <worker.cfg> <connector.cfg>
```

When we create a message with "null" values and send it into the topic, the Sink Connector is unable to insert the record into the TD table.